# Can I use Java on QNX?

Tags: java, embedded, qnx

I have to serve two masters. One project which is expected to split in two after v1.0.

It initially was a straightforward embedded project coded in C using FreeRTOS. It till could be until v1.0.

Afterwards, one master says we must use QNX to please a partner or lose a deal while another says that we must use J/XFS (Java [extension for financial services](http://www.jxfs.net/)) or lose another deal.

QNX doesn't exactly seem bustling with support for Java. The best that I can find is [this link](http://psy.swan.ac.uk/staff/carter/qnx/notes_java.htm), but t's hardly official.

So, can anyone shed more light on Java on QNX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have to say that I've never tried to use Java under QNX, so my answer is meant to help but it won't be definitive.

It seems to be pretty much something that 3rd parties need to provide, and obviously something QNX aren't too bothered about. They went from their own IDE that also ran under QNX to Momentics, based on Eclipse and therefore obviously requires Java, around version 6.3 and have not got a QNX version yet.

Going by [this reply](http://community.qnx.com/sf/discussion/do/listPosts/projects.community/discussion.qnx_momentics_community_support.topc4039?_pagenum=2) on the support forums you have existing options of:

- QNX partners Apogee Software or MicroDoc can provided updated support for IBM's J9 (from the link you found)
- Aonix  (PERC VM)
- Aicas (Jamaica VM)

I guess your other options would be to get an open source JVM and port it.

Comment: +1 Thanks very much for soem excellent feedback. I reslly appreciate it. (I doubt that I'm going to port a JAva VM, thoug :-)